# Multiple Select Case Statements in a Single Procedure

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to Autofilter 2 tables using `Select Case` statements and Autofilters in a single procedure. These are running from the worksheet itself and not a separate module - I'm wondering if this is my issue, as I am not sure when it is best to use modules vs. worksheet.

I have two separate `Select Case` statements affecting 2 different dropdown cells - `RegionChoice` and `ProjectType`. The autofilters based on `RegionChoice` (the 1st of these select case statements) run perfectly. However, the second `Select Case` statements' filters do not appear to work at all.

Filtering based on `RegionChoice` should affect both tables, but filtering based on `ProjectType` should affect just one of the two. Please see code below and thanks!

```vb
'Autofilter table on Summary Tab & CapEx Project Table on Visual based on Region drop down on Visual Tab
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsSumm As Worksheet, wsVis As Worksheet
    Dim range_to_filter As Range, range_to_filter_2 As Range
    
    Set wsSumm = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set wsVis = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Visual")
    Set range_to_filter = wsSumm.Range("A3:Z113")
    Set range_to_filter_2 = wsVis.Range("B80:T109")
    
    If Application.Intersect(Me.Range("RegionChoice"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Me.Range("RegionChoice").Value
    
    'Central
        Case Me.Range("A1").Value
            wsSumm.Unprotect ("fac1")
            range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="C"
            range_to_filter_2.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="C"
    'South
        Case Me.Range("A2").Value
            wsSumm.Unprotect ("fac1")
            range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="S"
            range_to_filter_2.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="S"
    'West
        Case Me.Range("A3").Value
            wsSumm.Unprotect ("fac1")
            range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="W"
            range_to_filter_2.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="W"
    'Northeast
        Case Me.Range("A4").Value
            wsSumm.Unprotect ("fac1")
            range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="NE"
            range_to_filter_2.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="NE"
    'Clear
        Case Me.Range("A5").Value
            wsSumm.Unprotect ("fac1")
           range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=4
           range_to_filter_2.AutoFilter Field:=5

    End Select
    
    If Application.Intersect(Me.Range("ProjectType"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Me.Range("ProjectType").Value
    
    'Refresh
        Case Me.Range("A9").Value
            wsVis.Unprotect ("fac1")
            range_to_filter_2.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Refresh"
    'Buildout
        Case Me.Range("A10").Value
            wsVis.Unprotect ("fac1")
            range_to_filter_2.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Buildout"
    'Maintenance
        Case Me.Range("A11").Value
            wsVis.Unprotect ("fac1")
            range_to_filter_2.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Maintenance"
    'Expansion
      Case Me.Range("A12").Value
            wsVis.Unprotect ("fac1")
            range_to_filter_2.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Expansion"
    'Furniture
      Case Me.Range("A13").Value
            wsVis.Unprotect ("fac1")
            range_to_filter_2.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Furniture"
    'Clear
      Case Me.Range("A14").Value
            wsVis.Unprotect ("fac1")
            range_to_filter_2.AutoFilter Field:=2

    End Select
End Sub
```

I initially had this structured as multiple `if`/`else` statements, but replaced w/ `Select Case` based on a SO user's feedback. It has proved a much more efficient solution, so I'd like to keep it if possible.

I was expecting the second `Select Case` statement based on cell `ProjectType` to behave in much the same way as the first based on `RegionChoice`. However, the autofilter statements are not running in any case.

Comment: You are exiting sub if the Intersects fail. So the first Intersect fails and it exits the sub before it ever checks the intersect for ProjectType.

Comment: You're not re-protecting your worksheets...

Comment: @tigeravatar  - thank you for pointing that out! So, are you saying I should omit "Is Nothing Then Exit Sub" after my intersect method?

Comment: Thanks, @TimWilliams - I actually meant to comment that out to later remove.

Comment: Wrap your first `Select Case` in `If Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("RegionChoice"), Target) Is Nothing Then ... End If`   Similarly for the second one.

Comment: @TimWilliams Do you mean End the IF Statement after my End Select statement? If so, I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly different structuring which will reduce your duplicated code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsSumm As Worksheet, wsVis As Worksheet
    Dim range_to_filter As Range, range_to_filter_2 As Range, crit As String
    
    Set wsSumm = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set wsVis = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Visual")
    Set range_to_filter = wsSumm.Range("A3:Z113")
    Set range_to_filter_2 = wsVis.Range("B80:T109")
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("RegionChoice"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case Me.Range("RegionChoice").Value
            Case Me.Range("A1").Value: crit = "C"
            Case Me.Range("A2").Value: crit = "S"
            Case Me.Range("A3").Value: crit = "W"
            Case Me.Range("A4").Value: crit = "NE"
            Case Me.Range("A5").Value: crit = ""
            Case Else: crit = ""
        End Select
        
        ApplyFilter range_to_filter, 4, crit
        ApplyFilter range_to_filter2, 5, crit
    End If
        
    If Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("ProjectType"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case Me.Range("ProjectType").Value
            Case Me.Range("A9").Value: crit = "Refresh"
            Case Me.Range("A10").Value: crit = "Buildout"
            Case Me.Range("A11").Value: crit = "Maintenance"
            Case Me.Range("A12").Value: crit = "Expansion"
            Case Me.Range("A13").Value: crit = "Furniture"
            Case Me.Range("A14").Value: crit = ""
            Case Else: crit = ""
        End Select
        
        ApplyFilter range_to_filter_2, 2, crit
    End If
            
End Sub

'Apply a filter to a range `rng`, using field number `fldNum`
Sub ApplyFilter(rng As Range, fldNum As Long, crit As String)
    If Len(crit) > 0 Then
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=fldNum, Criteria1:=crit
    Else
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=fldNum
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim - Once again, your experience is illuminating. Thanks so much for your help!